# Groovy: Update external variable form inside a closure

Tags: variables, groovy, closures

I have the following groovy code snippet below:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder;

def processData() {
     // xml builder
    def xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    xmlBuilder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    
    // data
    def body = [1, 2, 3]
    flag = '0'
    
    def idocXML = xmlBuilder.bind {
        ROOT {
            body.each { line ->
                flag = '1'
            }
        }
    }// end of xml builder bind
   
    println("$flag")
}

processData()
```

In the code snippet, there is a variable flag inside the processData initialized with 0, and inside the xmlBuilder.bind and iteration of body, I updated flag to 1. But outside of those closures, when I print the flag, it shows as 0.

How to have flag updated as 1 from inside the body.each closure? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is generally correct and will do what it supposed to do. The problem is that this `bind` closure is declared, but, actually, never called. You declared, how the XML should be constructed, but you never "triggered" the construction itself.
Let me show you what I mean and how did I find it out. My first question was, is this `flag = '1'` line is executed at all? I've changed the code by adding an additional output:

```
body.each { line ->
    println "line = $line" // this is the line I've added.
    flag = '1'
}
```

As you see, it prints nothing. Why? Because, as I wrote above, you described how your `idocXML` object must be constructed, but you never used the object. That is why this binding closure was never called. Here is the code that works as expected:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder;

def processData() {
    // xml builder
    def xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    xmlBuilder.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    // data
    def body = [1, 2, 3]
    flag = '0'

    def idocXML = xmlBuilder.bind {
        ROOT {
            body.each { line ->
                println "line = $line" // make sure that binding is actually calledd
                flag = '1'
            }
        }
    }// end of xml builder bind

    println idocXML.toString() // do something with the object to actually call binding

    println("$flag") // now, at that point, the flag will have a new value, because the binding logic updated it.
}

processData()
```

I hope it helps.